# How conditionally show the content of a div rather than another div in a JSP page?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I am very new in JSP development and I have the following doubt.

If into a JSP page I have 2 **div** like this:

```
<div id="succes">
    <p>SUCCESS</p>
</div>
<div id="failure">
    <p>FAILURE</p>
</div>
```

and I have to show only one of these div according to the value of a **status** variable putted into the  **Http Session** that can have only 2 value: **OK** and **KO**.

Can I do something like this:

```
<% if(request.getSession(false).getAttribute("status")=="OK"> { %>
    <div id="succes">
        <p>SUCCESS</p>
    </div>
<% } %>

<% else { %>
    <div id="failure">
        <p>FAILURE</p>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

It works? Is it ok? or there are some better way to achieve this task? (maybe can I do something like this using JavaScript\JQuery?)

Comment: Everything is alright just use `equals()` to compare strings.

Comment: there is always better way of doing it rather than using jsps. you can go with something easy, like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. But if you prefer not using jquery, there is a way of doing in js as well.

Comment: @sfat can you provide me an example of JQuery use for choose what div show according to the value of a variable inside the session?

Comment: Looks ok or you can look into using the JSTL namespace...using conditionals with JSTL tends to be easier to read than a scriptlet.

Comment: This is a very simple example , but you could potentially use css to style your DIV correctly which means you actually create  id="% request.getSession(false).getAttribute("status")%" <p>% request.getSession(false).getAttribute("message")%</p>

Comment: @AndreaNobili http://jsfiddle.net/wnhzynf1/ a basic example, but this can be adapted to your case pretty easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JSPs the right way to do it is using JSTL tags. Google for 'jstl tutorial' and read up what is offered.Your example uses scriptlets instead. Though that would get it done too but is not the right way to do it. One example is shown below:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test= "${request.getSession().getAttribute("userName").equals("Guest")}">
        <div> Welcome Guest</div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div> Welcome Real User</div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```